# Integrate Verhoeff algorithm into Javascript and HTML to check credit card form

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm

I'm trying to integrate [this code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Checksums/Verhoeff_Algorithm#JavaScript) in my pre-existing code (which I put together by looking around the web, it's for an admission test; they don't expect for me to know these languages, but still I have to meet certain requests). I tried to integrate it myself into my Javascript and to search for similar queries (like [this](https://www.laravelcode.com/post/how-to-verify-aadhar-card-number-without-any-api?utm_content=cmp-true), that I don't think it's what I'm looking for), but both to no avail. Ideally, I'd like for the credit card sequence to be checked when I click outside the textbox and then to have said textbox colored with RGB 231,0,100 if it's wrong (as of now, it calls another function that only checks for some characters). Could you please help me?
PS: I have other Javascript functions going on, but I omitted them from this question as they aren't pertaining the issue.

HTML

```
                    <!--Debit/Credit Card input; I set the type to password as an added layer of security-->
                    <label for="card" data-mlr-text>Card</label>
                    <input type="password" id="cardBox" placeholder="Write your Credit/Debit Card here" title="Write your Credit/Debit Card number" pattern="\d{10,19}" required onfocusout=validateCard()>
```

Javascript

```
// to validate before clicking Submit
var validName = false
var validCard = false
var validEmail = false
var validCVV = false


function validateName() {
    var name = document.getElementById("nameBox")
    var pattern = /^([^0-9]*)$/
   validName =  validate(name, pattern)
}

function validateEmail() {
   var name = document.getElementById("emailBox")
    var pattern = /\w+@\w+\.\w+$/
    validEmail = validate(name, pattern)
}

function validateCard() {
   var name = document.getElementById("cardBox")
    var pattern = /\b\d{16}$/
    validCard = validate(name, pattern)
}

function validateCVV() {
   var name = document.getElementById("cvvBox")
    var pattern = /\b\d{16}$/
    validCVV = validate(name, pattern)
}

function validate(box, pattern)
 {
  var nameVal = box.value
    if (pattern.test(nameVal)) {
        box.style.background = "white"
        return true

    } else {
        box.style.background = "rgb(231, 0, 100)"
        return false
    }
 }

function submitForm() {

 if (!validName || !validEmail || !validCard || !validCVV) {
        alert ("Please correct your input data ")
 }
}
```

This is what I fumbled together, but of course it doesn't work. When I do different tries, I also modify the function called in the HTML file accordingly. Please bear in mind that I'm very green and that the point of the task isn't to check my (non-existent) knowledge, but my resourcefulness in finding solutions.

```
// multiplication table d
var d=[
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5], 
    [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6], 
    [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7], 
    [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
    [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1], 
    [6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2], 
    [7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3], 
    [8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4], 
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
];

// permutation table p
var p=[
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
    [1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4], 
    [5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2], 
    [8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7], 
    [9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0], 
    [4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1], 
    [2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5], 
    [7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8]
];

// inverse table inv
var inv = [0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// converts string or number to an array and inverts it
function invArray(array){
    
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array) == "[object Number]"){
        array = String(array);
    }
    
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array) == "[object String]"){
        array = array.split("").map(Number);
    }
    
    return array.reverse();
    
}

// generates checksum
function generate(array){
        
    var c = 0;
    var invertedArray = invArray(array);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < invertedArray.length; i++){
        c = d[c][p[((i + 1) % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];
    }
    
    return inv[c];
}

// validates checksum
function validate(array) {
    
    var c = 0;
    var invertedArray = invArray(array);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < invertedArray.length; i++){
        c=d[c][p[(i % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];
    }

    return (c === 0);
}
var box = document.getElementById("cardBox");
if (c === 0) {
    box.style.background = "rgb(137,200,46)";
} else {
    box.style.background = "rgb(231,0,100)";
  
}
```

I also tried this variation, but I'm really grasping at straw here, it's way above what my current JS understanding is. Could anyone please help me understand what I'm getting wrong?

```
function verify() {
        var box = document.getElementById("cardBox");
        if(validate(box)) {
            box.style.background = "rgb(137,200,46)";
        } else {
            box.style.background = "rgb(231,0,100)";
        }  
}
```

Technically, any input that *isn't* a valid credit card sequence shouldn't give the "c === 0" result (as far as I understood), so I'm testing like that. If I get a failed result like I'm supposed to (with the pink background), then I'd test a valid one (namely, my credit card, as to have a plausable valid sequence).

Comment: `generate` is not defined.

Comment: It is for another function among those that, as I said, I omitted from the post. None of those functions have anything to do with what I'm trying to achieve here. I didn't want my question to become overtly verbose. Do you think they could be relevant? If so, I could add them.

Comment: If it is not relevant, then remove its calls from your code. Try to present the *minimal* code to reproduce the problem you have. Make sure you have included the **attempt** to make it work, and remove anything that is not related to your question, but still enough to be able to run it without obvious errors. For instance, I cannot imagine that all that CSS has anything to do with your question, nor language options, nor `<br>`,`<hr>`,`<p>` tags, ...etc. Remove all that distracts from your question. From what I understand the presented HTML should only need an `<input>` element. Nothing else.

Comment: Thank you! I removed everything that is not related to the question. As you can see from my profile, I'm very inexperienced, both in these languages and this site. My attemps to make it work were just copy-pasting the linked code and trying to meld it together with my existing one, but I was going there blindly. I also tried to modify codes made for similar things, but I'm not experienced enough to be able to do that. It's way above what I could do right now. I just need someone to kindly explain to me how to do a Javascript Verhoeff with a HTML input, as I found nothing explanatory on the web

Comment: I added the only source I think went close to what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure it was what I'm looking for, as the code is quite different from the first link of my question.

Comment: Did you attempt to use the code you linked to? What went wrong? Please show what code you tried with and what the problem is. Do you have examples of inputs that you can test with: inputs that should be valid, and others that shouldn't?

Comment: I also tried to include the aforementioned Verhoeff code into my existing JS, but it's even harder for me how to understand how to make that work.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the mention of debit/credit card input, because as far as I know those don't derive their checkdigit via the Verhoeff method. Are you sure you need Verhoeff's system? I think it is a different mechanism: Luhn's algorithm.

Comment: *"it just didn't work"* is not a good problem description. If it validates a number as incorrect while it is correct, then please also provide a test case with which to reproduce that behaviour.  (This should be inside the question).

Comment: According to the info I found, Verhoeff should be a more reliable algorithm for credit/debit cards than Luhn, so I went with that. By "it just didn't work", I mean that it doesn't do what I'd like it to do: changing the color of the box upon discovering if a sequence is correct or not. So it doesn't validate an incorrect number or viceversa, it just does nothing. Probably because I messed up somewhere, but I don't don't know where, hence the question. As for test cases, any real credit card sequence should work, while any made up shouldn't. Is this what you referred to?

Comment: *"Verhoeff should be a more reliable algorithm for credit/debit cards than Luhn"*: but they are not interchangeable: if the checkdigit in your credit card number was made with the Luhn algorithm, you cannot assume that it will pass a Verhoeff validation or vice versa. I will not dwell on this question. Maybe someone else can explain.

Comment: For this task, I need to validate credit card numbers. My knowledge on this stops here. I've read that the Luhn algorithm is less reliable than the Verhoeff one. I don't know anything else about it, I just assumed it was true. Also, the task doesn't say that the credit/debit cards that need to be validated are generated only on the Luhn algorithm, it just says that it should be able to validate any credit card. I don't know, maybe there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Like I wrote above and will repeat once more: you must know with which algorithm a check digit was encoded into the credit card number. The two mentioned algorithms produce different check digits, and so you cannot validate a number with a different algorithm. You should read upon the subject to see which credit card numbers used which algorithms. From what I read almost all credit card numbers have checkdigits that were generated with the Luhn algorithm, so using the Verhoeff algorithm is useless. I don't understand why you went to the Verhoeff algorithm. I suggest you research this subject.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A friend was able to help me out, so I take no credit for this. Solution (as with above, I omitted other JS scripts; added CSS to show color change):

HTML

```js
// multiplication table d
var d=[
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5], 
    [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6], 
    [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7], 
    [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
    [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1], 
    [6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2], 
    [7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3], 
    [8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4], 
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
];

// permutation table p
var p=[
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
    [1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4], 
    [5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2], 
    [8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7], 
    [9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0], 
    [4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1], 
    [2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5], 
    [7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8]
];

// inverse table inv
var inv = [0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// converts string or number to an array and inverts it
function invArray(array){
    
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array) == "[object Number]"){
        array = String(array);
    }
    
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array) == "[object String]"){
        array = array.split("").map(Number);
    }
    
    return array.reverse();
    
}

// generates checksum
function generate(array){
        
    var c = 0;
    var invertedArray = invArray(array);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < invertedArray.length; i++){
        c = d[c][p[((i + 1) % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];
    }
    
    return inv[c];
}

// validates checksum
function validateCardNumber(array) {
    
    var c = 0;
    var invertedArray = invArray(array);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < invertedArray.length; i++){
        c=d[c][p[(i % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];
    }

    return (c === 0);
}

function verify() {
        var box = document.getElementById("cardBox");
            const values = box.value.split("");
        const integers = values.map((value) => parseInt(value.trim(), 10));
        if(validateCardNumber(integers)) {
            box.style.background = "white";
        } else {
            box.style.background = "rgb(231,0,100)";
        }  
}
```

```css
body {  
    /*setting the green colour per request, just semi-transparent to highlight the wireframe*/
    background-color: rgba(137, 200, 46, .5);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: calibri;
    color: rgba(60, 60, 59);
}

.button {
    background-color: rgba(231, 0, 100);
    border: 1px;
    color: rgba(60, 60, 59);
    padding: 4px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 35px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: calibri;
}

#wireframe {
    background-color: rgba(137, 200, 46);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 4px solid #3c3c3b;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}

/*this is going to be the wrapper for the two footers; I'm dividing them in case I want to do different things with them*/
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

#footer1 {
        padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    position: sticky;
    left: 500px;
}

#footer2 {
        padding: 23px;
    float: right;
    position: sticky;
    right: 400px;
}

/*As with the body bg colour, the hr is semi-transparent*/
hr {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: -1%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: rgba(60, 60, 59, .5);
}

div.settings {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 96.7px 203.3px; 
    grid-template-rows: 33.3px 33.3px 33.3px 33.3px 33.3px; 
    gap: 10px 43px; 
    grid-template-areas: 
        ". ."
        ". ."
        ". ."
        ". ."
        ". ."; 
}

div.settings label { 
    text-align: right; 
}

div.settings label:after { 
    content: ":"; 
}

input[type=text] {
    width: max;
}

#image {
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px gray;
    width: 60px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    user-select: none;
    text-decoration:line-through;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Calibri;
    border: red 2px solid;
    margin-left: 10px;
     
}

#user-input {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #3c3c3b;
    width:auto;
        margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    height: 40px;
        border: #700064 0px solid;
}
input {
    border:1px #3c3c3b solid;

}
.inline {
    display:inline-block;

}

/* Commented out as it's not working as it should: white before clicking on it, pink if clicking out when the input is invalid. It does turn green when the input is valid, though.
input:invalid {
    background-color: rgba(231, 0, 100);
}

input:valid {
    background-color: rgba(137, 200, 46);

} */

input:required {
    border-color: rgba(60, 60, 59);
}

.grey-mode {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

#scroll {
    color:  rgba(60, 60, 59);
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en", "it", "es">
<head>
    <title data-mlr-text>Validation Page</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--I used ANSI instead of UTF-8 to incorporate all the possible variations of letters for the Name form-->
    <meta charset="ANSI">
    <meta name="viewport" content=
        "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="captcha.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="softwareDevTechnicalChallenge_TaskOne_Development.css">
        <script src="captcha.js"></script>
    <!--I divided the JS files and linked them separately, because I had some issue with some code and it felt better in working on them separately-->
    <!--Keeping this script out of the body and separate from others as I've seen some conflict among them, if they're in the same section-->
    <script src="softwareDevTechnicalChallenge_TaskOne_Development_5.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="generate()">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="wireframe">
        <form>
            <!--action="mailto:test@dn-uk.com" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="EmailForm"-->
            <div class="settings">
            
                    <!--Name and surname input-->
                    <label for="name" data-mlr-text>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="nameBox" placeholder="Write your full name here" title="Write your full name" pattern="\w{1,747}" required onfocusout=validateName()>

                    <!--Email input; I figured an email couldn't be smaller than 5 characters, even minimized like a@m.a-->
                    <label for="email" data-mlr-text>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="emailBox" name="email" placeholder="Write your email address here" title="Write your email address" maxlength="345" minlength="5" required onfocusout=validateEmail()>

                    <!--Card provider choice-->
                    <label for="provider" title="Choose your Debit/Credit Card's provider" data-mlr-text>Provider</label>
                        <select id="scroll" name="provider" title="provider">
                            <option value="visa" title="visa">Visa</option>
                            <option value="mcard" title="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
                            <option value="aexpr" title="americanexpress">American Express</option>
                        </select>
                        <!-- Commented out because it messes with the formatting and sizes
                        <input type="radio" id="visa" name="card_providers" value="Visa">
                        <label for="visa">Visa</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="mastercard" name="card_provider" value="Mastercard">
                        <label for="mastercard">Mastercard</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="americanexpress" name="card_provider" value="American Express">
                        <label for="americanexpress">American Express</label>-->

                    <!--Debit/Credit Card input; I set the type to password as an added layer of security-->
                    <label for="card" data-mlr-text>Card</label>
                    <input type="password" id="cardBox" placeholder="Write your Credit/Debit Card here" title="Write your Credit/Debit Card number" pattern="\d{10,19}" required onfocusout=verify()>

                    <!--CVV/CVC input-->
                    <label for="cvv">CVV/CVC</label>
                    <input type="text" id="cvvBox" placeholder="CVV/CVC" title="Write the security number on the back of your card" pattern="\d{3,4}" required onfocusout=validateCVV()><br>

                    <div id="user-input" class="inline">
                            <input type="text" id="submit" placeholder="Captcha code" required/>
                        </div>
 
                        <div class="inline" onclick="generate()">
                            <i class="fas fa-sync"></i>
                        </div>
 
                        <div id="image" class="inline" selectable="False">
                        </div>
 
                        <p id="key"></p>

            </div>
                <!--do the button with an Alt text and the captcha-->
                <div class="button">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" type="submit" title="Click to submit your credentials!">
                </div>

            
    </div>
        </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <div id="footer">
        <hr>
        <form>
            <div id="footer1">
                <!--To view the page with shades of grey-->
                <p name="gshades" title="Click to see the page in shades of grey" onclick="shadesOfGrey()" data-mlr-text>View in Greys</p>
            </div>

            <div id="footer2">
                <!--To view the page in another languages-->
                
                <label for="language" title="Choose another language" data-mlr-text>Change Language</label>
                <select name="language" class="mb-POCControls_Selector" id="mbPOCControlsLangDrop">
                    <option id="scroll" value="en">English</option>
                    <option id="scroll" value="it">Italiano</option>
                    <option id="scroll" value="es">Español</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

<script src="softwareDevTechnicalChallenge_TaskOne_Development.js"></script>
<script src="softwareDevTechnicalChallenge_TaskOne_Development_2.js"></script>
<script src="softwareDevTechnicalChallenge_TaskOne_Development_3.js"></script>
<script src="softwareDevTechnicalChallenge_TaskOne_Development_4.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).